# Stylelint: force empty line at bottom of nested block

Tags: css, stylelint

I can’t seem to find exactly what I want in the rules & documentation. I want to force an empty line at the bottom of a nested rule.

```
@media print {

  a {
    color: red;
  }
            /* <----- Force this empty line here */
}
```

I see the rule: `rule-nested-empty-line-before` which will force a new line at the top of the media query.

And I see the rule: `block-closing-brace-empty-line-before` which will force a new line at the end of the block, but that would also force a new line after `color: red`.

I feel like an older version of Stylelint used to have a rule that would do it but I can’t seem to figure it out any more.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure I'd call this a bug, but maybe the rule `block-closing-brace-empty-line-before` should add a new option to handle this, could you create a new stylelint issue for this so the team can discuss this further please https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/new